# Are unicoins and features shared across stackexchange sites?

Tags: support, unicoins

I see that unicoins are used to buy features in stackexchage sites. I have some questions about them.

1. Are unicoins shared across my stackexchange accounts?
2. Are the features I buy with unicoins shared across my stackexchage accounts? Or I can use them only where I bought them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can only use them where you bought them and different sites use their own amount of unicoins too.